# Is there always a f(u,v) for $a(u,v)\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial u}+b(u,v)\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial v}=1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

for any a(u,v),b(u,v).

Is there always f(u,v) such that $a(u,v)\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial u}+b(u,v）\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial v}=1$

I don't know how to change it to a system

$\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial u}=\frac{1}{a(u,v)+b(u,v)}$

$\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial v}=\frac{1}{a(u,v)+b(u,v)}$

May not have solution because 
$\frac{\partial }{\partial v} \frac{1}{a(u,v)+b(u,v)}$ may be not equal to $\frac{\partial}{\partial u} \frac{1}{a(u,v)+b(u,v)}$

Answer (score 1):

Using your idea $f_p(u,v)=\frac{u+v}{a+b}$  gives for the difference $g(u,v)=f(u,v)-f_p(u,v)$ the homogeneous equations
$$
a\frac{∂g}{∂u}+b\frac{∂g}{∂v}=0
$$
Introduce a change in variables $g(u,v)=h(\frac{u+v}{a+b},\frac ua-\frac vb)$ resulting in the equation ${∂h}{∂x}(x,y)=0$, so that
$$
h(x,y)=C(y)\implies f(u,v)=\frac{u+v}{a+b}+C\Bigl(\frac ua-\frac vb\Bigr)
$$
where $C$ is an arbitrary differentiable function.

---

To avoid most of the possibilities where the coordinate change has a singularity, use the scaling rotation
$$
\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\-b&a\end{bmatrix}
·
\begin{bmatrix}u\\v\end{bmatrix}
$$
so that for $f(u,v)=h(au+bv,-bu+av)$ one gets the differential equation
$$
1=(a^2+b^2)\frac{∂h}{∂x}(x,y)\implies h(x,y)=\frac{x}{a^2+b^2}+C(y)\\~\\
f(u,v)=\frac{au+bv}{a^2+b^2}+C(-bu+av)
$$

Comment: thank you for your answer.I didn't write clearly in title .I'm sorry ,a =a(u,v)and b =b(u,v）are function of u,v not const numbers. And I don't all the solution .I only need one

Comment: Then you are in the full theory of hyperbolic PDE. As with first order ODE, there are some with easy solutions, but with most problems, existence theory is the most that you will be able to do.